# Solve $x^2\equiv a$ mod $\prod P_i^{e_i}$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Suppose we have the solutions to  $x^2\equiv a$ mod $P_i^{e_i}$. How do we find solutions to $x^2\equiv a$ mod $\prod P_i^{e_i}$. For example, I know $x^2\equiv  1$ mod $3$ has solution $\pm 1$ mod $3$ and  $x^2\equiv  1$ mod $5$ has solution $\pm 1$ mod $5$. Can we construct all the solutions to  $x^2\equiv  1$ mod $15$ from them? Can we use Chinese remainder theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. You have to start from a *Bézout's relation* between $3$ and $5$:
$$2\cdot 3-1\cdot 5=1$$
Now if you have solutions $a$ mod. 3 and $b$ mod. $5$, we deduce  solutions mod. $15$:
$$x\equiv b\cdot 2\cdot 3-a\cdot 1\cdot 5=6b-5a\mod15.$$

Comment: What's the justification for the last line $x\equiv b\cdot 2\cdot 3-a\cdot 1\cdot 5$? Is it Chinese remainder thm?

Comment: It's a formula deduced from Bézout which should be known by heart. Reduce mod $3$ and mod $5$, and check it works since, viz. $2\cdot 3\equiv 1$ and .$1\cdot 5\equiv 0\mod 5$.